# Pandas - Fill N rows for a specific column with a integer value and increment the integer there after

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe to which I added say a column named `col_1`. I want to add integer values to that column starting from the first row that increment after every 4th row. So the new resulting column should have values of as such.

```
     col_1
       1
       1
       1
       1
       2
       2
       2
       2
```

The current approach I have is a very brute force one:

```
for x in range(len(df)):
    if x <= 3:
        df['col_1'][x] = 1
    if x >3 and x <= 7:
        df['col_1'][x] = 2
```

This might work for something small but when moving to something larger it will chew up a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there si default `RangeIndex` you can use integer division with add `1`:

```
df['col_1'] = df.index // 4 + 1
```

Or for general solution use helper array by lenght of DataFrame:

```
df['col_1'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 4 + 1
```

For repeat `1` and `2` pattern use also modulo by `2` like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(20, 40)})
df['col_1'] = (np.arange(len(df)) // 4) % 2 + 1
print (df)
     a  col_1
0   20      1
1   21      1
2   22      1
3   23      1
4   24      2
5   25      2
6   26      2
7   27      2
8   28      1
9   29      1
10  30      1
11  31      1
12  32      2
13  33      2
14  34      2
15  35      2
16  36      1
17  37      1
18  38      1
19  39      1
```

Comment: That works, way better, thank you. Just one more question what if after say when the integer value gets to 2 I want to rest the integer back to 1, how can I do that

Comment: @user9996043 - Not sure if understand, do you think `df['col_1'] =  np.where((np.arange(len(df)) > 3) & (np.arange(len(df)) <= 7), 2, 1)` ?

Comment: @user9996043 - Or `a = df['col_1'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 4 + 1` and then `df['col_1'] = np.where(a > 2, 1, a)`

Comment: The `df['col_1'] = np.where(a > 2, 1, a)` seems like it should work, but upon trying it still seems to keep updating after rather than resetting back to 1. So, it kept going to 1, 2, 3, 4 (for 4 rows each) rather than 1, 2, 1, 2 (for 4 rows each)

Comment: @user9996043 - Not 100% sure if understand, what is expected output for `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(20, 40)})` ?

Comment: 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 and so on staring from the index 20, since from index 0 to 19 it would be 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 (for 4 rows each)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204212/discussion-between-jezrael-and-user9996043).