# Creating rank based on index value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data-frame like this

```
name      qty1  qty2    set_id
0   name0   2   5      1000
1   name1   1   7      1000
2   name2   0   4      1000
3   name3   6   6      1000
4   name4   8   8      1000
5   name5   0   3      1000
```

I want to update the set_id column like this. (for every nth row(here 3rd row) new set id to be updated.)

```
name      qty1  qty2    set_id
0   name0   2   5           1
1   name1   1   7           1
2   name2   0   4           2
3   name3   6   6           2
4   name4   8   8           3
5   name5   0   3           3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.RangeIndex` and `repeat`:

```
N = 2  # 3rd row
df['set_id'] = pd.RangeIndex(1, 1+len(df)//N).repeat(N)
print(df)

# Output:
    name  qty1  qty2  set_id
0  name0     2     5       1
1  name1     1     7       1
2  name2     0     4       2
3  name3     6     6       2
4  name4     8     8       3
5  name5     0     3       3
```

Or the same with `np.arange`  and `np.repeat`:

```
N = 2  # 3rd row
df['set_id'] = np.repeat(np.arange(1, 1+len(df)//N), N)
print(df)

# Output:
    name  qty1  qty2  set_id
0  name0     2     5       1
1  name1     1     7       1
2  name2     0     4       2
3  name3     6     6       2
4  name4     8     8       3
5  name5     0     3       3
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use a `list comprehension` and assign it's return to your set_id column:

```
df['set_id'] = pd.Series([(i+1) for i in range(len(df)) for n in range(2)])
```

prints:

```
        name  qty1  qty2  set_id
0  0   name0     2     5       1
1  1   name1     1     7       1
2  2   name2     0     4       2
3  3   name3     6     6       2
4  4   name4     8     8       3
5  5   name5     0     3       3
```

You can adjust the number in `range(2)` to determine your 'nth' row, as you call it.

Answer (score 0):

As your index is already linear, the simplest is to divide it by 2 as integer and add 1:

```
df['set_id'] = df.index//2+1
```

output:

```
    name  qty1  qty2  set_id
0  name0     2     5       1
1  name1     1     7       1
2  name2     0     4       2
3  name3     6     6       2
4  name4     8     8       3
5  name5     0     3       3
```

*NB. if you don't have a linear index, you can use `numpy` to generate the linear range:*

```
import numpy as np
df['set_id'] = np.arange(len(df))//2+1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59323904/pandas-fill-n-rows-for-a-specific-column-with-a-integer-value-and-increment-th

Comment: funny, looks like you know already all the SO ;)

Comment: ya, many answered solutions ...